# Missing short cuts created in Windows 10 Start Menu after upgrade to Windows 11

Tags: windows-11-upgrade

I just upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11.
Now I lost the short cuts that I previously created in Windows 10 Start Menu.
Where can I find it and put them back on Windows 11?

Comment: Why can't you just recreate them? What were they shortcuts to exactly?

Comment: I created many shortcuts to various directories that I usually used to open it quickly in File Explorer. It will be great if there is a quick way to restore them in Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

The Start Menu in Windows 10 has changed to a Launcher in Windows 11.

So some items may have changed from Start Menu shortcuts to the Launcher.

Windows Tools is now part of the Start Menu in a different way than Windows 10 and if you had shortcuts for these, they may have been replaced by Windows Tools.

Open Start and look near the Top Right of the Start Menu, see All Apps (different location than Windows 10) and that shows all your apps. Look there.

The black, left click menu is very close in Windows 10 to Windows 11.

So look in the Launcher and in All Apps.  I have upgraded two machine and not actually lost shortcuts. They were replaced in the launcher and the new All Apps.

If indeed you actually lost 2 or 3 specific shortcuts, just make new ones.

Remember that Windows 11 is vastly different than Windows 10.

The Windows 10 (and prior operating systems) had the ability to create Toolbars (right click on the Task Bar .  That has been removed in Windows 11. In my Windows 10 system, Toolbar shortcuts were often in the Start Menu folders.

The All Apps button is in the top right of the Start menu:

[image: The All Apps button is in the top right]

Answer (score 1):

I found the old shortcuts are still available in **%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs** (we can open it with File Explorer).

We could then add the shortcut to the Launcher with **Pin to Start** option in the context menu.

[image]